# Trying to create my own image uploader (JSF)

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, facelets, tagfile

I want to upload images from the client to the server. I already managed to do it using gadgets like primefaces. But this time, i want to try to do it on my own i found information on the web on how to do it, but i am kind of stuck. 
My current problem is that the browser says to me that the tag that i created for doing the upload, is not bound. I would like to understand, why the application does not find it and how should i fix it.

I will paste all i did till now so you can help me find the mistake:

**1.Added commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar and commons-io-1.4.jar to the lib folder(Automatically get added to the classpath)**

[image]

**2.Created an xml that wil make the tag library available(This is placed inside WEB-INF folder)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
   <namespace>http://corejsf.com</namespace>
   <tag>
      <tag-name>upload</tag-name>
      <component>
         <component-type>javax.faces.Input</component-type>
         <renderer-type>com.corejsf.Upload</renderer-type>
      </component>
   </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**3.Create a package for the implementation of the tag and place in a new package called com.corejsf;**

[image]

Here is the source:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.render.FacesRenderer;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

@FacesRenderer(componentFamily="javax.faces.Input",
   rendererType="com.corejsf.Upload")
public class UploadRenderer extends Renderer {
   public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)  
      throws IOException {
      if (!component.isRendered()) return;
      ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

      String clientId = component.getClientId(context);

      writer.startElement("input", component);
      writer.writeAttribute("type", "file", "type");
      writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, "clientId");
      writer.endElement("input");
      writer.flush();
   }

   public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
      ExternalContext external = context.getExternalContext(); 
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) external.getRequest();
      String clientId = component.getClientId(context);
      FileItem item = (FileItem) request.getAttribute(clientId);

      Object newValue;
      ValueExpression valueExpr = component.getValueExpression("value");
      if (valueExpr != null) {
         Class<?> valueType = valueExpr.getType(context.getELContext());
         if (valueType == byte[].class) {
            newValue = item.get();
         }
         else if (valueType == InputStream.class) {
            try {
               newValue = item.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               throw new FacesException(ex);
            }
         }
         else {
            String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
            if (encoding != null)
               try {
                  newValue = item.getString(encoding);
               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                  newValue = item.getString(); 
               }
            else 
               newValue = item.getString(); 
         }
         ((EditableValueHolder) component).setSubmittedValue(newValue);  
         ((EditableValueHolder) component).setValid(true);  
      }

      Object target = component.getAttributes().get("target");

      if (target != null) {
         File file;
         if (target instanceof File)
            file = (File) target;
         else {
            ServletContext servletContext 
               = (ServletContext) external.getContext();
            String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath(target.toString());
            file = new File(realPath); 
         }

         try { // ugh--write is declared with "throws Exception"
            item.write(file);
         } catch (Exception ex) { 
            throw new FacesException(ex);
         }
      }
   }   
}
```

**4.Then I added a servlet  filter, to distinguish to intercept the requests and placed it in the same package as the custom tag implementation**

[image]

This is its source:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class UploadFilter implements Filter {
   private int sizeThreshold = -1;
   private String repositoryPath;

   public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
      repositoryPath = config.getInitParameter(
         "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.repositoryPath");
      try {
         String paramValue = config.getInitParameter(
            "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.sizeThreshold");
         if (paramValue != null) 
            sizeThreshold = Integer.parseInt(paramValue);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
         servletEx.initCause(ex);
         throw servletEx;
      }
   }

   public void destroy() {
   }

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
         return;
      }

      HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

      boolean isMultipartContent 
         = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpRequest);
      if (!isMultipartContent) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
         return;
      }

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      if (sizeThreshold >= 0)
         factory.setSizeThreshold(sizeThreshold);
      if (repositoryPath != null) 
         factory.setRepository(new File(repositoryPath));
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

      try {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<FileItem> items 
            = (List<FileItem>) upload.parseRequest(httpRequest);
         final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
         for (FileItem item : items) {
            String str = item.getString();
            if (item.isFormField())
               map.put(item.getFieldName(), new String[] { str });
            else
               httpRequest.setAttribute(item.getFieldName(), item);
         }

         chain.doFilter(new 
            HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {
               public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                  return map;
               }                   
               // busywork follows ... should have been part of the wrapper
               public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                  Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
                  return (String[]) map.get(name);
               }
               public String getParameter(String name) {
                  String[] params = getParameterValues(name);
                  if (params == null) return null;
                  return params[0];
               }
               public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
                  Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
                  return Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
               }
            }, response);
      } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
         ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
         servletEx.initCause(ex);
         throw servletEx;
      }      
   }   
}
```

**5.Then I registered the filter in the web.xml. (I wanted to use an annotation but I didn’t know how, does someon know how can I do that with an annotation?) 
Also added the corejsf.taglib.xml**

```
<!-- NEEDED FOR FILE UPLOAD -->
<filter>
      <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.corejsf.UploadFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sizeThreshold</param-name>
         <param-value>1024</param-value>
      </init-param>
</filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Upload Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/upload/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping> 

    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/corejsf.taglib.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

**6.On my WebContent folder I created a subfolder called upload(Destination of the uploaded files)**

[image]

**7.Inside a jsf page I use the tag for upload and submit and also use a managed bean method to create the file names:**

```
 ....

<corejsf:upload target="upload/#{placeAddController.prepareUniqueIdentifier}" />

 ....

<h:commandButton value="Dalje" style=" font-weight: bold;  font-size:150%; action="/submittedImage" />
```

And the java managedbean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PlaceAddControler {
…
public String prepareUniqueIdentifier() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"png";
    }
```

The error i see is when navigating to the page where the new tag is added is this:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /oglas.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 183] The prefix "corejsf" for element "corejsf:upload" is not bound.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:387)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:370)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

-What i am missing?

-What else do i need to do to transfer a file from the client to the serverfile system with an unique fileName, inside the upload folder.

My final goal is not to add this images into the database, just leave them in the file system.

I hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE**

I added the xmlns, to my page and that fixed the exception:

> xmlns:corejsf="http://corejsf.com"

But why when i click on the button, the file is not uploaded???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you need to add the XML namespace to the page, just like you'd do for Facelets, PrimeFaces, etc. This should solve the "prefix is not bound" error.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:corejsf="http://corejsf.com">
```

Comment: Yes i forgot that. That fixed the exception. Thanks. I still don't see the file in the upload folder, after i click submit. Why is that?

Comment: That I cannot see so immediately. I would recommend stepping through with a debugger if you haven't already.

Comment: Ok i will try. I already checked, and my form uses: `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` the only thing consfuses me is if is the `action="/submittedImage"` actually allowing the form to be submitted. How could i check that?

Comment: You need to make sure that the endpoint (I guess the filter in this case?) is actually hit when the form is submitted.

Comment: I am a bit new with JSF, i am trying to debug, but i dont really know to use the eclipse debugger, with JSF, could you give me a hand, to find the reason why the file does not get uploaded? How could i check if the filter is called? I placed breakpoints inside the filter class, but eclipse does not change to the debug perspective, i think i am not hitting the filter as you said.

Comment: You need to be running in Debug mode.

Comment: I placed the breakpoints, then i restarted in debug mode, but i get HTTP Status 404. I dont see the start page. Also i notice Step over is disabled. Is this the correct way of doing it?